github main branch isn't asking for compare & pull request when i git push on local feature branch
I was working on my project and made a few changes on the feature branch#1. I did git add ., git commit -m "commit message" and git push on my feature branch#1, normally github would show a compare & pull request on main branch for the commit I just pushed from feature branch#1, but this time main branch didn't prompt anything.
I've worked on this feature branch#1 before and everything was fine, I don't know what caused this. When I checked this feature branch#1 on github, it does say it's 1 commit ahead of main branch.
I created a second feature branch#2 to test it again, I followed the same procedure and this time github main branch showed me pull request, but when I checked the request it included the commits I pushed on my other feature branch#1 as well.
So, why isn't github asking me to compare & pull when I git push my commits from feature branch#1, yet it worked when I git push on feature branch#2 and it includes the commits I made from feature branch#1?

Usually this happens when you've already seen the pop-up once.

@SinaSarsharPour Really? Do you mean the pop-up won't appear again after I've seen it once? Because I've pushed commits multiple times on feature branch#1 before, and every time Github suggested a pull request.

Actually, you are right, just tested it with an old branch, and it showed up the banner after I pushed a commit

The error "x commit ahead of main branch" means, your local branch has commits that are not yet been pushed to the remote branch. Thus GitHub correctly doesn’t suggest a pull request, because there are no changes on the remote branch to merge into main.
So have you really pushed the commits from branch#1’ to the remote branch, or just committed? Did the git push` command fail?
To check if there are really unpushed commits, run the following command:
git log origin/branch#1..HEAD

If the output lists your last commit, run the git push command again. And if git push was successful, GitHub should now also propose an pull request with the latest changes from this commit.

Hi, thanks for replying and editing. What do you mean by local branch has commits that are not yet been pushed? If I didn't push commits from branch#1, the remote branch#1 wouldn't know if it's ahead of main branch no? Or am I being silly here? Also, I already pushed the commits from branch#1 when I was testing on branch#2, Github suggested a pull request which included the commits from branch#1 and branch#2.

If you have create git commits without push, the remote branch know about this commits, and display therefore the error: "x commit ahead of main branch"

But the fact that the changes that were in the commit from branch#1 are then in the pull request from branch#2 contradicts my assumption that these are non-pushed commits.
